# Reactive property is not propagating to component in Vue 3 app

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue 3 app. I am trying to setup a store for state management. In this app, I have the following files:

- app.vue
- component.vue
- main.js
- store.js

These files include the following:

**store.js**

```
import { reactive } from 'vue';

const myStore = reactive({
    selectedItem: null
});

export default myStore;
```

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';

import App from './app.vue';
import myStore from './store';

const myApp = createApp(App);
myApp.config.globalProperties.$store = myStore;
myApp.mount('#app');
```

**component.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="item">You have selected an item</div>
    <div v-else>Please select an item</div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="generateItem">Generate Item</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      item: Object
    },

    watch: {
      item: function(newValue, oldValue) {
        alert('The item was updated.');
      }
    },

    methods: {
      generateItem() {
        const item = {
          id:0,
          name: 'Some random name'
        };
        this.$emit('itemSelected', item);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**app.vue**

```
<template>
  <component :item="selectedItem" @item-selected="onItemSelected" />
</template>

<script>
  import Component form './component.vue';

  export default {
    components: {
      'component': Component
    },

    data() {
      return {
        ...this.$store
      }
    },

    methods: {
      onItemSelected(item) {
        console.log('onItemSelected: ');
        console.log(item);
        this.$store.selectedItem = item;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The idea is that the app manages state via a reactive object. The object is passed into the component via a property. The component can then update the value of the object when a user clicks the "Generate Item" button.

I can see that the `selectedValue` is successfully passed *down* as a property. I have confirmed this by manually setting `selectedValue` to a dummy value to test. I can also see that the `onItemSelected` event handler works as expected. This means that events are successfully flowing *up*. However, when the `selectedItem` is updated in the event handler, the updated value is not getting passed back down to the component.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$store.selectedItem` stops being reactive here, because it's read once in `data`:

```
data() {
  return {
    ...this.$store
  }
}
```

In order for it to stay reactive, it should be either converted to a ref:

```
data() {
  return {
    selectedItem: toRef(this.$store, 'selectedItem')
  }
}
```

Or be a computed:

```
computed: {
  selectedItem() {
    return this.$store.selectedItem
  }
}
```